# How to store large binary files in node js?

Tags: http, caching, node.js, webserver

I am trying to create a cache for nodejs. i was thinking of putting some cache data in memory and some in files, how do i store these large binary files in node js, without running out of memory. how do i know the memory limit has reached?

Comment: [`os.freemem`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#os.freemem)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an established caching layer with node? Redis is very well suited to this task.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple: yeah..im trying to create a in built memcache for nodejs. how much memory is available for storing contents in the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting the answer from the comment by Raynos :)..  you can just us os.freemem() to find the available memory in the system.